# Debug VBA macros

Tags: vba, excel

I have a excel file with macros. It's used like template for our program. Program opens this file, call macros and put data there as parametrs. The question is how can I debug this macros when it's called from the app? For example, in Visual Studio I can use "Attach to process", maybe there is something like this in VBA?

Comment: Do you want to know how to use Excel VBA debugger or how to setup your testing environment to simulate the scenario with Excel as the main test driver?

Answer (score 1):

I have a few different ways to perform debugging in Excel, and none of them are perfect or very sophisticated.

1. Use debug.print throughout your code to print to the Immediate window to see how the program is executing. This is useful in two scenarios - if you want to see generally how far along your program executed, or where it is in the process of executing, or alternatively, you can go in and add more detail using debug.print if your program is getting snagged somewhere specifically, and you want to see what is happening as the program is executing.
2. Create an array, enter log information into the array as the program executes, and print the array at the completion of the program execution. This is imperfect because it is not really useful in conditions where the program execution does not complete successfully, but it is useful in scenarios where you want to get some statistics about how the program ran as part of an autopsy.
3. Add Code Breaks in to the program so that you can see how the program is executing as it is run. Use the Immediate window to check on the values of variables in the program.

Again, none of these are perfect.

Comment: Break Points is actually what I need, but when macros called from program that doesn't works.

Comment: Is it possible to add the break point in the code in the secondary spreadsheet? That would solve your issue. Or is the issue that you don't have access to the secondary spreadsheet that is being opened by the primary program?

Comment: Program works with temporary copy of file. So, if I put a breakpoint in the code it's ignored.

Comment: Got it. I checked out this site (http://www.fmsinc.com/TPapers/vbacode/Debug.asp), which clarified the issue you are having - essentially, you cannot add breakpoints in and save the file. Two thoughts in this case: (1) add error handling to each procedure in the temporary file, and (2) add a MsgBox at the start of the execution of each procedure so that you know what is about to be executed. (This may be overkill, but I am assuming you are having a specific issue somewhere in your temporary file that you are trying to debug.) debug.print will be your friend in this scenario as well.

Comment: I have find the solution. I can use 'Stop' keyword for programmatically add a break point